# Replace a fragment within a Viewpager(notifyDataSetChanged does not work)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged, fragmentstatepageradapter

My MainActivity contains a viewPager.

In the MainActivity.java, I set the adapter for viewpager. The adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The fragment I want to replace is a 
cameraFragment. So when the user clicks on the switch camera button, I want to now show the camera fragment, this time with a front camera on.

On clicking the switch Camera button, I remove the fragment from the arraylist of fragments I had passed to the custom adapter. I add the new fragment and call notifydatasetchanged. However, this does not result in the new fragment being added. How do I achieve dynamic replacement of fragments within a viewpager which is backed my a custom fragment state pager adapter?
Code :

```
mainPageFragments = new ArrayList<>();
mainPageFragments.add(new ResultsFragment_());
mainPageFragments.add(DemoCameraFragment_.newInstance(false));
pagerAdapter = new MainViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),mainPageFragments);
```

To replace the fragment : On receiving the related event I do,

```
mainPageFragments.remove(1);
    if (event.getCameraState().equals(CameraSwitchButton.CameraTypeEnum.BACK)) {
        mainPageFragments.add(DemoCameraFragment.newInstance(false));
    } else {
        mainPageFragments.add(DemoCameraFragment.newInstance(true));

    }
    // Not Working...
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter Code :

```
public class MainViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsArray;

public MainViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsArray) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragmentsArray = fragmentsArray;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentsArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentsArray.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
}
```

Comment: post some code what you have done

Comment: @Mano. Any thoughts on how to update/replace a fragment? Clearly I'm missing something. I do not want to reset the adapter. It seems like an expensive operation(If the number of pages/ fragments increase. Also, I only need to replace a single fragment, so re-instantiating every other one makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Pleas post also code for MainViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: @Okas. Updated it with MainViewPagerAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

Your MainViewPagerAdapter.getItemPosition is the cause of your issue.

Default implementation always returns POSITION_UNCHANGED. For pager to remove your fragment you have to return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE for the fragments that are removed.

Additionally your current design contradicts with the idea of FragmentStatePagerAdapter. From the FragmentStatePagerAdapter [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html): "This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages."

Your current implementation holds all fragments in an array, and so defeats this mechanism. Correct implementation would be to create fragments in MainViewPagerAdapter.getItem method and let the adapter to handle fragments lifecycles as needed.

Comment: Even if I were to implement the adapter this way, how do I replace the fragment? I had already read up on the default implementation of getItemPosition.  The reason I went with the FragmentStatePageAdapter is that there's a good chance the number of pages in the viewpager will increase. I still can't figure out what I should do in the getItemPosition method, to fix my issue. Thanks.

Comment: You have to separately keep track which fragment(s) you want to keep and which one(s) to remove. Then, when something changes you have to call notifyDataSetChanged(). Pager will then call your adapter getItemPosition method. You have to return POSITION_NONE for those you want to remove and then pager will remove those for you.

Comment: Thanks @Okas. I made changes based on your post and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Okas. I made the following change to getItemPosition within my FragmentStatePagerAdapter subclass.

```
@Override
 public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof DemoCameraFragment_)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

I added logs to the OnCreate of both my fragments to confirm if they were getting recreated or not. As per my requirement, only the second fragment is recreated.